# security dump-keychain -d

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm having troubling finding an details on what -d switch means in security : https://ss64.com/osx/security.html

In the commandline :

**security dump-keychain -d login.keychain** , what is the use of the "-d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online manpages can be outdated or incomplete. Check the command itself:

```
$ security help dump-keychain

Usage: dump-keychain [-adir] [keychain...]
    -a  Dump access control list of items
    -d  Dump (decrypted) data of items
    -i  Interactive access control list editing mode
    -r  Dump the raw (encrypted) data of items
```